# Getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis errors but my parenthesis are all paired

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-00907

I have this query and it works fine when run the query by itself:

```
SELECT                                                                                                                                                               
c.factDate,                                                                                                                                                          
c.agentOsLoginId,                                                                                                                                                    
c.person,                                                                                                                                                            
c.systemName,                                                                                                                                                        
c.siteId,                                                                                                                                                            
c.callId,                                                                                                                                                            
c.callType,                                                                                                                                                          
c.agentId,                                                                                                                                                           
c.GMTStartTime,                                                                                                                                                      
c.GMTStopTime,                                                                                                                                                       
c.duration,                                                                                                                                                          
c.evalInitiatedTime,                                                                                                                                                    
      TO_DATE (to_char (from_tz(cast(c.GMTStartTime as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')  EasternStartTime,     
      TO_DATE (to_char (from_tz(cast(c.GMTStopTime  as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')  EasternStopTime,      
TRUNC(TO_DATE (to_char (from_tz(cast(c.GMTStartTime as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')) EasternfactDate       
from m_NPInteraction c                                                                                                                                               
where c.factDate >= trunc( add_months ( sysdate, -3 ), 'MM' )
```

But when I add this query to my data conversion code, it is throwing ORA-00907.

Here's what it looks like when I put it in the conversion code:

```
$class=com.merced.dice.translate.conduits.jdbc.MetaBeanTypeSource
$scope=global

configuration=(creator:/com/merced/dice/Configuration)
metaBeanType=(creator:/com/merced/apps/perform/recordtypes/NPInteractionEvalChunk)

queryBeanFormat="\
SELECT                                                                                                                                                               --\n\
c.factDate,                                                                                                                                                          --\n\
c.agentOsLoginId,                                                                                                                                                    --\n\
c.person,                                                                                                                                                            --\n\
c.systemName,                                                                                                                                                        --\n\
c.siteId,                                                                                                                                                            --\n\
c.callId,                                                                                                                                                            --\n\
c.callType,                                                                                                                                                          --\n\
c.agentId,                                                                                                                                                           --\n\
c.GMTStartTime,                                                                                                                                                      --\n\
c.GMTStopTime,                                                                                                                                                       --\n\
c.duration,                                                                                                                                                          --\n\
c.evalInitiatedTime,                                                                                                                                                 --\n\   
      TO_DATE (to_char (from_tz(cast(c.GMTStartTime as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')  EasternStartTime,     --\n\
      TO_DATE (to_char (from_tz(cast(c.GMTStopTime  as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')  EasternStopTime,      --\n\
TRUNC(TO_DATE (to_char (from_tz(cast(c.GMTStartTime as timestamp), 'GMT') at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')) EasternfactDate       --\n\
from m_NPInteraction c                                                                                                                                               --\n\
where c.factDate >= trunc( add_months ( sysdate, -3 ), 'MM' )
"
```

When it complied it throws ORA-00907. What am I missing here? Is there a quirk of Oracle that I don't know about? Or do I have some syntax error that also throws ORA-00907? Maybe somewhere in the WHERE clause? I'm not that experienced in Oracle so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the line number to the error message? It would help a lot to know where to start looking.

Comment: The application I'm using does not provide the line number.

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

rootCause=SQLException #1: errorCode: 907 sqlState: 42000 message: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: that's indeed odd, it's missing closing bracket but i don't see any missing right bracket there. I will have to create a sample table and test your query

Comment: i totally overlooked that you noted the statement worked fine by itself. What I suspect now is, that `queryBeanFormat` somehow escapes a parenthesis somewhere. Did you check various quitation methods?

Comment: Thank you. you are probably correct. The platform we use changes the quotation marks. I will need to use two instead of one.

Comment: That was it!!. Needed to double up on the single quotes.